# simple python question about urlopen

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that deletes all the tags in html document. So I made a program like this.

```
import urllib
loc_left = 0
while loc_left != -1 :
    html_code = urllib.urlopen("http://www.python.org/").read()

    loc_left = html_code.find('<')
    loc_right = html_code.find('>')

    str_in_braket = html_code[loc_left, loc_right + 1]

    html_code.replace(str_in_braket, "")
```

but It showes the error message like below

```
lee@Lee-Computer:~/pyt$ python html_braket.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "html_braket.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 25, in <module>
    import string
  File "/home/lee/pyt/string.py", line 4, in <module>
    html_code = urllib.urlopen("http://www.python.org/").read()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

And one thing that is interesting is, what if I typed the code into python, the error above wouldn't show up.

Comment: I don't get that error when I try your program.  Are you sure you've posted the whole program?

Comment: really? I had to modify some part of code, such as typo like loc_left, loc_right + 1 to loc_left : loc_right + 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've named a script `string.py`. The `urllib` module imports this, thinking that it's the same `string` module that's in the stdlib, and then your code uses an attribute on the now partially-defined `urllib` module that doesn't yet exist. Name your script something else.

Answer (score 1):

Step one is to download the document so you can have it contained in a string:

```
import urllib
html_code = urllib.urlopen("http://www.python.org/").read() # <-- Note: this does not give me any sort of error
```

Then you have two pretty nice options which will be robust since they actually parse the HTML document, rather than simply looking for '<' and '>' characters:

Option 1: Use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

''.join(BeautifulSoup(page).findAll(text=True))
```

Option 2: Use the built-in Python HTMLParser class

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class TagStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

Example using option 2:

```
In [22]: strip_tags('<html>hi</html>')
Out[22]: 'hi'
```

If you already have BeautifulSoup available, then that's pretty simple.  Pasting in the TagStripper class and strip_tags function is also pretty straightforward.

Good luck!